# Cocoa OS X - Change background of window in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, uistoryboard, nswindow

I am making an app for OS X with Cocoa with Xcode and I want to change the Windows background color with alpha in swift. I don't know how to call the window from the code and how to set its background color with alpha value. How can I do that?

Here is my app delegate class, with hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: AppDelegate is **_not_** a view controller. It does not have a `view`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the AppDelegate is not the right place to add it if you are using storyboards. There is an easy way by modifying the view's layer:

1. In Interface Builder, select the child view that is held by the view controller of the Window.
2. Go to the the view's Effects Inspector and enable Core Animation Layer.

[image]

3. Add this line of code in your `viewDidLoad()` method `(viewcontroller.swift)`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad() 
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 
       self.view.wantsLayer = true;
       self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code and pictures to the Core Animation.  That solved most of my problems.  I then found that because more was going on later with windows that I needed to move your code to viewWillAppear.  It has been much more predictable there.  I got this information from another question on SO and thought I would update this thread as well since it was my starting point on the problem.

The following goes in viewController.swift after you have enabled Core Animation Layer for the View in the Effects Inspector.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

Comment: Actually no need to use viewWillAppear, you just need to add line `self.view.wantsLayer = true;` before using the layer.